# Rails Tutorial Sample App 6.26

Tags: railstutorial.org

I am following along with the sample_app everything runs create and all specs pass until I get to 6.26. As soon as I add the has_secure_password to the User class I receive a Ruby interpreter error that is 1899 lines long. The buffer in vim only shows up to line 600 so I can't even get to the root of the problem. I have verified that I have all of the gems with the correct version numbers. Not sure where to go from here. I am not sure where to start debugging from here. I have made sure to rake db:migrate and rake db:test:prepare. Any help in where to start debugging or direction to take would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You're probably missing the bcrypt-ruby gem.

> You need to add bcrypt-ruby (~> 3.0.0) to Gemfile to use
>   has_secure_password:
>
> gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

Comment: I am using bcrypt-ruby 3.0.1 as the tutorial states.

Comment: Well I believe I have narrowed things down. Weird but if I run guard from a standard Iterm2 everything works. It is only when running a tmux session that I get the error. bcrypt-rub-3.0.1 Segmentation fault. Not sure why tmux would be causing the issue but I am starting to look into the crash reports

Answer (score 0):

This error had nothing to do with Rails Tutorial or RSpec. It ended up being an issue with running guard within a tmux session. Everything works fine if I open a second tab and run guard in a standard terminal.